# MIPS Selection Sort Not Working

Tags: sorting, selection, mips, swap

I am trying to write a selection sort algorithm in MIPS but am having problems. I have tested my swap and findSmallest functions individually and they appear to be working but when I run the code I get some addresses (I'm assuming) in the output.

```
                .data
            .align  2
values:     .word   12, 15, 13, 2, 25, 3, 5
valueCount: .word   7

initialPrint:   .asciiz "\Unsorted Array: \n"
donePrint:  .asciiz "\n Sorted Array: \n"
comma:      .asciiz ", "

        .text
        .globl  main

main:       # Beginning stuff
        la  $a0, initialPrint   # load initialPrint string into a0
            li  $v0, 4          # set code (4) to print string
            syscall             # print initialPrint

            la  $s6, values
            la  $s7, valueCount
            lw  $s7, 0($s7)     # extract valueCount word from s7
            move    $a0, $s6        # move values into $a0 for function call
            move    $a1, $s7        # move valueCount into $a1 for function call
            jal printList       # print initial array


            li  $s1, 0          # index = 1

selectionSort:  # Middle stuff
        bge $s1, $s7, endPrint
        move    $a0, $s6        # move values into $a0 for function call
            move    $a1, $s7        # move valueCount into $a1 for function call
        move    $a2, $s1        # move index into $a2 for function call
            jal findSmallest        # Let's get this show on the road
            move    $a0, $v0        # move smallestIndex into a0
            move    $a1, $s1        # move currentndex into $a1
            move    $a2, $s6        # move values into $a2

            jal swap            # swap
            move    $s6, $v0        # move swapped array into $s6


            addi    $s6, $s6, 4     # next position in array
            addi    $s1, $s1, 1     # index++
            j   selectionSort


            # Ending stuff
endPrint:       la  $a0, donePrint      # load donePrint string into a0
            li  $v0, 4          # set code (4) to print string
            syscall             # print donePrint
        move    $a0, $s6        # move values into $a0 for function call
            move    $a1, $s7        # move valueCount into $a1 for function call
            jal printList       # print initial array
            li  $v0, 10         # load end call
            syscall             # end

##########################################################################################
#############   findSmallest Function   ##################################################
##########################################################################################

## takes in array, current index, and valueCount
## examines all elements from n-index through n
## outputs index of lowest value    

findSmallest:   ## Begin Function   
        addi    $sp, $sp, -24       # preserve state before function call
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)     
        sw  $s0, 4($sp)
        sw  $s1, 8($sp)     
        sw  $s2, 12($sp)        
        sw  $s3, 16($sp)
        sw  $s4, 20($sp)
        sw  $t1, 24($sp)            
## s0 = values
## s1 = valueCount
## s2 = index   
## s3 = smallestIndex   
## s4 = smallestValue
## t1 = currentValue
        ## Function Body
        move    $s0, $a0        # move values into s0
        move    $s1, $a1        # move valueCount into s1
        move    $s2, $a2        # move index into s2

        lw  $s4, 0($s0)     # load first word
        addi    $s0, $s0, 4     # move to next word
        addi    $s2, $s2, 1

floop:      bge     $s2, $s1, endLoop   # if index >= valueCount then done
        lw  $t1, 0($s0)     # load currentValue     
        ble $s4, $t1, skip      # if smallestValue < currentValue then skip
        move    $s4, $t1        # set smallestValue = currentValue
        move    $s3, $s2        # set smallestIndex = currentIndex
skip:
        addi    $s0, $s0, 4     # iterate to next word in values
        addi    $s2, $s2, 1     # index++
        j   floop           # repeat loop

endLoop:    move    $v0, $s3    
        # End Function Stuff
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)     # restore state before function call    
        lw  $s0, 4($sp)
        lw  $s1, 8($sp)     
        lw  $s2, 12($sp)        
        lw  $s3, 16($sp)
        lw  $s4, 20($sp)
        lw  $t1, 24($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 24        

        jr  $ra




##########################################################################################
#############   swap Function   ##########################################################
##########################################################################################  

swap:       # Begin Function    
        addi    $sp, $sp, -32       # preserve state before function call
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)     
        sw  $s0, 4($sp)     
        sw  $s1, 8($sp)     
        sw  $t1, 12($sp)        
        sw  $t2, 16($sp)        
        sw  $t3, 20($sp)        
        sw  $t4, 24($sp)
        sw  $s6, 28($sp)

        # main function
        move    $s0, $a0        # move smallestIndex into function
        move    $s1, $a1        # move targetIndex into function
        move    $s6, $a2

            sll $s0, $s0, 2
            add $t1, $s0, $s6
            lw  $t2, 0($t1)         # get the value from the array cell

            sll $s1, $s1, 2
            add $t3, $s1, $s6
            lw  $t4, 0($t3)         # get the value from the array cell

            sw  $t2, 0($t3)
            sw  $t4, 0($t1)


        move    $v0, $s6

        # End Function      # restore state before function call
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)     
        lw  $s0, 4($sp)     
        lw  $s1, 8($sp)     
        lw  $t1, 12($sp)        
        lw  $t2, 16($sp)        
        lw  $t3, 20($sp)        
        lw  $t4, 24($sp)
        lw  $s6, 28($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 32        

        jr  $ra


##########################################################################################
#############   printList Function   #####################################################
##########################################################################################

# a0 - values array (address)
# a1 - valueCount (word)

# s6 - values
# s7 - valueCount (word)


printList: 
## Setup
        ## Begin Function   
        addi    $sp, $sp, -16       # allocate stack space for 3 values
        sw  $ra, 0($sp)     # store return adder
        sw  $s6, 4($sp)     
        sw  $s7, 8($sp)
        sw  $s0, 12($sp)

        move    $s6, $a0
        move    $s7, $a1
        li  $s0, 1          # index = 1
print:      
        lw  $a0, 0($s6)
        li      $v0, 1          # load output call
            syscall             # output value
            la  $a0, comma      # load comma string into a0
            li  $v0, 4          # set code (4) to print string
            syscall             # print initialPrint
            addi    $s6, $s6, 4
            addi    $s0, $s0, 1
            ble $s0, $s7, print


# End Function Stuff
        lw  $ra, 0($sp)     # store return adder
        lw  $s6, 4($sp)     
        lw  $s7, 8($sp)
        lw  $s0, 12($sp)
        addi    $sp, $sp, 16

        jr  $ra
```

My output:

```
Unsorted Array: 
12, 15, 13, 2, 25, 3, 5, soSorted Array: 
25, 1684370546, 13, 3, 540703073, 1869835861, 1953656659,
```

It has to be something with the way the array is being stored because there are memory addresses in the output.

Answer (score 0):

I found a number of issues in your code:

```
move    $a0, $v0        # move smallestIndex into a0
move    $a1, $s1        # move currentndex into $a1
move    $a2, $s6        # move values into $a2

jal swap            # swap
```

Here you're passing a couple of indices that are relative to *the beginning of the array*, but `$s6` is incremented at the end of each iteration, so it will only point to the beginning of the array during the very first iteration. Instead of `move $a2, $s6` you should use `la $a2, values`.

---

```
move    $s6, $v0        # move swapped array into $s6
```

This should be removed altogether.

---

```
move    $a0, $s6        # move values into $a0 for function call
move    $a1, $s7        # move valueCount into $a1 for function call
jal printList
```

Here you should place the base address of the array in `$a0`, so it should be `la $a0, values` instead of `move $a0, $s6`.

---

And in `findSmallest` you don't seem to initialize `$s3` for the case where the first element is the smallest one.